# JQuery Selectors for Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is not exactly a programming problem but more of a quest for more clarity on DOM manipulation using JQuery or Javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

i have a couple lines below i just need to understand how they are treated in the browser. the idea is just understand a little more

I know this line creates a reference to an Object, but what Object??
   `var child = $("select[Title='Country'], select[Title='Country Required Field'],select[Title='Country possible values']");`

Does line empty the value property in this object? Why do you need this?
   `$(child).empty();`

`var options = <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>;`

i know this is supposed to append the variable to the child object but what happens if there is already other values in the child object. What if you need to replace the values already in the child object with new the values in the option variable.
`$(child).append(options);`

the question is just for more clarity any answers will be welcomed thanks

Comment: Start  with [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/topics) http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/512/dom-manipulation#t=201701050932189339683 http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/389/selectors#t=201701050932221380253

Comment: Thanks so much... the links were really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that what you mean but if you want to override the current options in the select fields by the options you've in the `options` variable without using `empty` you could use `.html()` :

```
$(child).html(options);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`$(child).empty();` this line doesn't empty the `value` property of the object but it clears all the inner HTML of this object. This means it clears all the `option` tags inside the object. If you need to modify an existing value of an `option` with some other value you can do this:

```
`$("option[value='oldvalue']", child).val('new value');
```

The above code selects the `option` whose value you need to modify and then set its value to new value.

Comment: thanks so much for this
`var optionvar =$("option[value='oldvalue']", child)`
i see you have passed two arguments in the DOM object, so does it mean select  `option` from the object `child` you passed as the second argument that has a value property whose value is `oldvalue`

and then going further optionvar holds an object from the child object and the you use the .val('new value') to change the value of the value property

is my understanding correct?